# Can you combine two tkinter tk widgets?

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I am creating an app which will have two Tk() widgets. Is it possible to combine them side into one larger widget side by side to make the app easier to use?

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=400, height=150)
canvas.pack()

tk2 = Tk()
canvas2 = Canvas(tk2,width=400, height=150)
canvas2.pack()

tk.mainloop(), tk2.mainloop()
```

When I do this to make the basic windows, I obviously get two seperate windows. Can that be combined into one?

I am a beginner and am using python 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but you can create two Frames inside your main Tk.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SubWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        x = tk.Text(self)
        x.pack()

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.win1 = SubWindow(self)
        self.win1.pack(side="left")
        self.win2 = SubWindow(self)
        self.win2.pack(side="right")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    main.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the code to make Frames resize when window does:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SubWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        x = tk.Text(self)
        x.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.win1 = SubWindow(self)
        self.win1.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.win2 = SubWindow(self)
    self.win2.pack(side="right", expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have two instances of `Tk` in the same app. If you want multiple windows, you should create instances of `Toplevel`. If you want everything in one window you would create instances of `Frame` and arrange them however you want (side by side, top to bottom, in a grid, etc).

While it's possible to have multiple instances of `Tk`, there are side effects that can cause unexpected problems. Tk (upon which tkinter is built) was designed to have a single root widget.